# System Settings icons missing with Numix uTouch

Tags: icons

I am using the Numix uTouch icon theme, some of the icons on System Settings are not [replaced](http://imagebin.org/300935). This is [how it should look](http://imagebin.org/300936).

Currently on 14.04...

Comment: Did you also install `numix-icon-theme`? I think you need to install `numix-icon-theme` to have the whole set.

Comment: i used command:"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme-utouch"

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme`. Also check out Numix Shine and Circle: `sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme-{shine,circle}`.

Comment: thanks，but the icons on "System Settings" were not replaced when i install "numix-icon-theme-{shine,circle}" and selected them

Comment: How did you selected them?

Comment: i used “Unity Tweak Tool”

Answer (score 0):

We no longer maintain uTouch, you should consider switch to http://me4oslav.deviantart.com/art/Numix-Circle-Linux-Desktop-Icon-Theme-414741466

Comment: "gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid."